# how to construct mysql query with bias with items that appear multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to construct a query to display items for a user from the ITEM table randomly but according the number of times that the category of the item exists in the PREFERENCE table (bigger bias) .
The categories have to be added in the query automatically.

```
ITEM TABLE
Itemname   Category Id
'item1', '20081'
'item2 ', '15032'
'items3', '20081'
'item4', '20081'

PREFERENCE TABLE
Userid, Categoryname, Categoryid
'79', 'Everything Else', '15032'
'146', 'Antiques', '20081'
'79', 'Antiques', '20081'
'79', 'Antiques', '20081'
'79', 'Antiques', '20081'
```

In a simple sense it is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `ex`.`item` where category_id=20081 or category_id=79 /*there rest to be added automatically and also with the bias depending on the count in preference  */order by rand();
```

Comment: Are there multiple entries for `79/20081` on purpose in your preference table?

Comment: He says he wants to bias by the number of times the category appears in the preference table, so it seems like that's on purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.*
FROM item i
JOIN (SELECT Categoryid, COUNT(*) cat_count
      FROM preference
      WHERE Categoryid IN (20081, 79)
      GROUP BY Categoryid) p
ON i.Categoryid = p.Categoryid
ORDER BY cat_count*RAND() DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    preference
        WHERE   (p.userid, p.categoryid) = (79, i.categoryid)
        ) AS pref
FROM    item i
LEFT JOIN
        preference p
ON      (p.userid, p.categoryid) = (79, i.categoryid)
WHERE   category_id IN (20081, 79)
ORDER BY
        RAND() + 1 - POW(0.7, pref)
LIMIT 25
```

The ordering value will be uniformly random within [0, 1) for unbiased items, [0.3, 1.3) for 1 preference, [0.51, 1.51) for 2 preferences etc.

You might want to come up with a more complex formula for bias